# Next.js: How to get URL path inside getStaticPaths?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want get last number by current url pathnames inside getStaticPaths.

```
http://localhost:3000/category/food/2 -> 2,
http://localhost:3000/category/food/3 -> 3,
...
```

I tried.

```
 export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  // getAllCategories() is fetch(GET) allcategories
  const allCategories = await getAllCategories() //  fetch;

  const num = 2; <- Get number by current url pathnames

  return {
    paths:
      allCategories.edges.map(
        ({ node }: { node: { [key: string]: string } }) =>
          `/category/${node.slug}/${num}`
      ) || [],
    fallback: false,
  };
};
```

Dose anyone know how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you are on the wrong way with just *getStaticPaths* because it is pre-rendered at build time and you do not have access to the path.

You should combine it with *getStaticProps* where you get a context object to use; for details please read the official documenation -> https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props and https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths